# Expectation of maximum of two independent random variable with known distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, uniform-distribution

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables such that $X\sim \textrm{Unif}(0,1)$ and $Y=e^{-t}\times a $ where $t\sim \mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $a\sim \textrm{Unif}(0,1)$. What is $\mathbb{E}[\max(X,Y)]$?

Update: $X$, $t$ and $a$ are all independent random variables. By $Exp(\lambda)$, I meant the exponential distribution with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Comment: You haven't told us the _joint_ distribution of $t$ and $a$.  Are they independent?

Comment: "$\mathrm{Exp}(\lambda)$" sometimes means exponentially distributed with expected value $\lambda$ and sometimes means exponentially distributed with expected value $1/\lambda$. Which is intended here? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks for your comment. $t$, $X$ and $a$ are independent random variables. Also $Exp(\lambda)$ is exponential distribution with mean $1/\lambda$.

Comment: What did you try? There are some classical venues here...

Comment: It is standard convention to use CAPITAL letters for random variables, and lower case for parameters. In your case, $t$ and $a$ are actually random variables, and so should be notated with capitals to avoid unnecessary confusion.

Comment: It is quite easy to solve this using a computer algebra system ... The joint pdf of random variables $(X, T, A)$ is, by independence $f(x,t,a)$: $$f = \frac{\lambda }{e^{\lambda  t}}$$ and `domain[f] = {{x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, Infinity}, {a, 0, 1}};`  ...............You seek:   `Expect[Max[x, Exp[-t] a], f]`  which returns the solution $$ \frac{2 \lambda +3}{3 \lambda +6}$$ (using the `Expect` function in _mathStatica_).

Answer (score 0):

A quick start, based on what seems obvious and a bit of simulation,
but without doing all the steps:

If T ~ EXP(1), then exp(-T) ~ BETA(1, 1) = UNIF(0, 1), Max has
support (0,1) and E(Max) = .5555.

If T ~ EXP(rate=2), then  Y ~ BETA(2, 1) and E(Max) = .58.

In R (and probably about the same in Matlab):

> m = 10^6;  x = runif(m);  a = runif(m);  lam = 1
>
> t = rexp(m, lam);  y = exp(-t)*a;  w = pmax(x,y)
>
> hist(exp(-t), prob=T);  mean(w)

[1] 0.5554506

I'm new to this, if partial answers and simulated clues for questions
with "classical elements" are not appreciated here, then tell me so, 
and I will desist.